Warning de Vulnerabilidad en spring al agregar FeignClient
Tengo un proyecto en Java con Spring Boot, en el cuál quiero usar Feign Client. Al agregar las dependencias para poder utilizarlo, me sale el warning:

Vulnerability found in dependency: CVE-2023-24998
7.5 Transitive Allocation of Resources Without Limits or Throttling vulnerability with High severity found

Agregué las dependencias de apache commons file upload para intentar solucionar el problema, ya que por lo que pude investigar es un error de la versión 1.5 de apache commons. Pero eso tampoco le quita el warning.
Quisiera saber si saben a que se debe y si pueden ayudarme a solucionarlo, o si no es nada y debo ignorarlo.
Les dejo las dependencias que les comenté.
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2023.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-openfeign -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-fileupload2-jakarta-servlet6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload2-jakarta-servlet6</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M2</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

Y acá mi archivo pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>LIBRARY</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>LIBRARY</name>
    <description>LIBRARY</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-fileupload2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2023.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-openfeign -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-fileupload2-jakarta-servlet6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload2-jakarta-servlet6</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

